# Pandas count number in one column based off a condition in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I need to count the number of times id occurs given the condition that enroll > 0. This is what I have so far...Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks!

```
raw_data = [['a', '0'], ['a', '0'], ['a', '1'], ['b', '0'], ['b', '0.5'], ['c', '0'], ['c', '0']]
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['id', 'enroll'])
df
```

[image]

```
def countidsperenroll():
    for i in df['id']:
        if (enroll>0):
            return value.count()
        continue
```

The result should be a table with:
the values:

```
3
2
0
```

because there were 3 `'a'` ids and there was an `enroll`> 0 with one of the '`a`' ids. And because there were 2 '`b`' ids and there was an `enroll` > 0 with one of the '`b`' ids. No '`enroll`' for the '`c`' id, So that gets a 0.

Answer (score 8):

We can do it two steps with `value_counts`

```
s=df.id.value_counts()
s.loc[~s.index.isin(df.loc[df.enroll>0,'id'].unique())]=0
s
a    3
c    0
b    2
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby("id").filter(lambda x: (x["enroll"]>0).any()).groupby("id").count()
```

First you groupby to filter out the groups that have at least one enroll greater than 0 than you groupy again to get the aggregate data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that if enroll is greater than 0, then the sum per group will be greater than 0 :

```
(
    df.assign(temp=df.groupby("id").enroll.transform("sum").gt(0))
    .groupby("id")
    .temp.sum()
)

id
a    3.0
b    2.0
c    0.0
Name: temp, dtype: float64
```